# Server control library calling its own services

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, wcf, web-services

I am posting this as a part of my effort in searching the best possible design solution for my requirement.
I am currently working on a complex server control(not user control) in asp.net which is going to be rendered into html elements on the client side.
And those html elements needs to do a ajax call backs to the server using js/jquery.
 Here is the problem. As this is a serverside control and can be added into any application/domain. I dont want to have those callback services hosted separately. Is there any way that I can host those server callback services in the same library? If so, how can I access them from the client side?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried putting a WebService into a ServerControl, but I know you can create a composite control (a server control that inherits form the CompositeControl class) that has an update panel in it.  With that you can do server side processing with asynchronous calls from the client, similar to JQuery calling a WebService.